# JasperReport Plugin Struts2 force download

Tags: struts2, force-download, jasper-plugin

I'm using Struts2, Spring and Hibernate for my web app.
Now, I'm trying to generate PDF reports with jasper reports struts plugin.
I add the result-type to struts.xml file:

```
    <result-types> 
        <result-type name="jasper" class="org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult" default="false"/> 
    </result-types>
```

Action definition:

```
    <action name="vf" class="packaget.InvoiceAction" method="seeInvoice">
         <result name="success" type="jasper">
             <param name="location">/WEB-INF/reports/invoice.jasper</param>
             <param name="dataSource">invoiceSource</param>
             <param name="format">PDF</param>
             <param name="contentDisposition">filename="Invoice.pdf</param>
             <param name="documentName">Invoice.pdf</param>
             <param name="reportParameters">invoiceParameters</param>
         </result>
    </action>
```

And here is my action class:

```
public class InvoiceAction extends BaseAction implements Preparable {       
  ...
  public String seeInvoice(){
         List<Invoice> invoice= new ArrayList<Invoice>();
         facturas.add(new Invoice());
         invoiceParameters.put("message","test");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

I want to generate a download popup, I don't want to see the report in the browser. 
How can I force this? `contentDisposition` or `documentName` params has no effect...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<param name="contentDisposition">filename="Invoice.pdf</param>` you are missing '"', is it a typo?

Comment: Hi Umesh, i put " at the end of the value, but has no effect... what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, this is a interesting topic, you can config your browser to ask for location to save the downloaded file instead save it to the default location

Comment: @jzafrilla: seems everything ok to me, i am suspecting that the content type is not setting as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add "attachment" to the content disposition.

```
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment</param>
```

And remove the **filename="Invoice.pdf"**.
This param does the same as documentName. Using them together will duplicate this information in the HTTP response.

```
<param name="contentDisposition">filename="Invoice.pdf"</param>
```